# Hide categories div block, Expand slideshow 100% from responsive layout

Tags: html, css, opencart2.x

I am using the http://themeglobal.com/opencart/kingstore/doc/#!/layout template

Below the menu i want to hide the categories block and expand the slideshow and two banners to 100%, (the slideshow winn all available space and the banners stay the size they are).

I do not want to have white space where categories previous exists.

I do comment this line  `class="col-sm-<?php echo $grid_center; ?>"` an try to play with the css class fixing at 12 , i still have white space to fill .

How can i have the slide show fullwidth without the categories ? ( themeglobal.com/opencart/kingstore/doc/#!/layout ) and keep it responsive.

```
<?php //$grid_center = 12; if( count($headerleft) ) { $grid_center = 9; } ?>
<?php $grid_center = 11; ?>
<div class="col-sm-<?php echo $grid_center; ?>">

<div class="row">
<?php
   $grid_header_top = 12;
   $grid_content_right = 3;
   $header_right = $modules_old_opencart->getModules('header_right');
   if( count($header_right) ) {
      if($grid_center == 9) {
         $grid_header_top = 8;
         $grid_content_right = 4;
      } else {
         $grid_header_top = 9;
         $grid_content_right = 3;
      }
   }
?>
```

Here is the original : [Demo Kingstore lite](http://themeglobal.com/opencart/kingstorelite/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing category module ( position - header left) from admin panel > Design > Layout > Your layout name (Home) .

If possible put more code from catalog/view/theme/applied_theme_name/template/common/home.tpl file

Edit : It works for me by removing just category module from layout (tested on version 2.1.x). 
Found below code :

```
    <?php $grid_center = 12; if( count($headerleft) ) { $grid_center = 9; } ?>
        <div class="col-sm-<?php echo $grid_center; ?>">
                <div class="row">
                <?php 
                $grid_header_top = 12; 
                $grid_content_right = 3;
                $header_right = $modules->getModules('header_right'); 
                if( count($header_right) ) {
                    if($grid_center == 9) {
                        $grid_header_top = 8;
                        $grid_content_right = 4;
                        } else {
                        $grid_header_top = 9;
                        $grid_content_right = 3;
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
```

It seems that you have changed first line please revert these changes and try.

Hope this help you.

Comment: in another way i need a left div for the slideshow with a right div for 2 banners one above another and that they fit 100% of the outer div. And that it becames responsive  i just download this theme from http://themeglobal.com/opencart/kingstore/doc/#!/layout

Comment: i do already remove the categories div but could not fit the 3 remaining divs